# Testing the hypothesis on clustering

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, clustering

I have a number of samples. For each, there is a time course of multivariate data defined, with $t$ timepoints ($t < 50$) and $n$ variables ($n > 100$). We have noted that the time courses of a certain further variable $X$ *seem* to split this group of samples in two. We would like to use the $n \times t$ variables to test this hypothesis.

How would you handle this problem? I'm a bit lost at the moment. I was considering using PCA or MPCA and than an acceptable clustering technique to see whether we can recover the original clustering. However, several alternative clusterings could be possible in the given data set (for example, we can have red and blue circles and triangles). I'm not sure how to test the following statement:

There exists a *substantial* (significant? statistically significant?) set of variables that show the same pattern of clustering as $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Clustering is not the appropriate method to *test* an hypothesis. Clustering is a way to *find* hypotheses to study and test carefully afterwards. Clustering is *exploratory* and a *discovery* technique.

The reason is that clustering is unsupervised. It will just try to find some interesting hypothesis; but that does *not* imply that hypotheses not found by clustering aren't sound. Any clustering method makes some assumptions on the hypotheses to be found (e.g. least variance partitionings, as found by k-means). **At most you can measure how similar your hypothesis is to the assumptions made by a particular algorithm.** e.g. if your result is similar to those found by k-means, it means your result has a low variance.

What you essentially want is to see if your hypothesis is a good *predictor*, isn't it? Treat it as a **classification problem**, which are much easier to evaluate (e.g. cross-validation, leave-one-out, etc.)

Comment: As far as I know, you _can_ test a clustering hypothesis, see http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~casella/Papers/paper-v3.pdf or the SAS manual: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_introclus_sect010.htm. My problem is here that I have both variables and time points.

Comment: You "can" do a lot, but it often does not make sense, because the prior assumptions are wrong. You can test which "k" is best, but if your data does not have k-means type of clusters, then the result will be crap even if you choose the "best" k. Similarly, many tests for the "significance" of clusters are actually just tests *against* uniform distribution of data. If your data were uniformly distributed, you wouldn't bother to cluster it anyway...